# How to configure switch stacking on Dell Z9100-ON switches?

Tags: dell

I feel like this has to be a stupid question and I should be able to find the answer somewhere - but I can't find it...

Is there, anywhere, a concise document that explains how to configure Dell Z9100-ON network switches in a stack?  In particular (or at least, to start with), I can't figure out how to set a given switch's stack-unit number, and all of my usual Google searching and documentation scouring is failing me.  I can find stacking configuration information for other (primarily FTOS) Dell switches, but not the Open Networking type switches.  I'm not sure where to even begin looking in the documentation - I expected to find a section like "Configuring Switch Stacking" or something like that (as I find such documentation for other switches), but I find no such thing for the Z9100-ON.

Am I missing something very very obvious?

Comment: I don't think that switch is a stackable switch; not all switches are stackable. There is nothing about it in the data sheets, and that is something about which Dell would brag. Nor do I find any mention of it in any of the reviews.

Comment: I was led to believe it was.  If that's actually the case ... that would indeed be "missing something very very obvious"...  :-)

Comment: I think you are going to have to bite the bullet and call Dell...

Comment: Also, if you find out anything, please post an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: Datasheet don't mention stacking. You can try a command like  "stack-unit 1 renumber 2"... If it's not working, I'm 99% sur this is not a stackable switch

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: The answer that was posted did not help.  What did help was your initial comment - this simply isn't a stackable switch.  I had just been (mis)informed that it was stackable.

Answer (score 1):

This switch support "L2 multipath support via Virtual Link Trunking (VLT)
and multiple VLT (mVLT) multi-chassis link aggregation
technology"

This is supposed to be a "a more resilient and manageable alternative to stacking".

try this link for configuration

http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/networking-z9100/z9100-on-9.10.0.0-config-pub/reconfiguring-stacked-switches-as-vlt?guid=guid-0bb984c9-4b11-4935-8f59-5b0351cd4aff&lang=en-us